# Cannot normally underline slash characters and hyperlinks

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, operators, style, hyperlink

Really, if you evaluate `Style["/", Underlined]` or type / and set the font of the character to be underlined through **Format**|**Font...**, you get $/$, not $\underline{/}$.
What I want to do is to underline a hyperlink, but...
[image]
the output is ugly. Note, that line has a gap before ".com".
This is not the problem of 'Courier New' only. I think this behavior caused because `/`, `//`, `.`, etc. are operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `UnderBar` instead of `Style[...,Underlined]`:

```
Hyperlink[UnderBar[#], #] &@ "http://www.wolfram.com/Sine.html"
```

[image]

Note: The issue you observe is mentioned in the docs [Underlined >> Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Underlined.html):

> *Underlined* will recursively affect all elements of an expression

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't guess to use under-bar operator, instead I sticked to text formatting.

Comment: @Danylo, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.