# Two issues about Underline(d)

Tags: documentation, built-in-symbols

From the Help Browser

```
Style["abcd xyz", FontVariations -> {"Underline" -> True}]
abcd xyz
```

The text is NOT Underlined, contrary to the [online version](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontVariations.html)

Also

```
Style["Text 2012", Underlined]
```

will return Text and 2012 underlined.
How is it possible to have a continuous underline?

Comment: Ad 1 - works well on Win7 V10.2. Ad 2 - duplicate: [Cannot normally underline slash characters and hyperlinks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80681/5478)

Comment: You execute the first piece of code in the document, right? Something seems to be wrong with the document page of `Style` and `FontVariations`.

Comment: It does not want in Version 9 and still it is in the Help Browser. Regarding Ad 2 thank you for the great link. That's what I needed.

Comment: @xzczd: Curiously the problem arises when I execute the code directly from the Help Browser. When I copy-paste in a notebook and run the code it works as desired.

Comment: I believe this unanswered question is related to the first issue: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96740/1871

Comment: I thought I am losing my mind:-)! Thanks for pointing out the question.